# How to listen for a communication on a port without knowing what IP its coming from in python using sockets?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, ip, port

I am trying to make a network between some computers in python and I want to make it so that I can have another computer send information to my IP address and on a set port. Which my computer can then receiving from just listening on that port not know what IP the information has come from.

(I do not know if this is possible but any help would be amazing)

```
resv_conection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
resv_conection.connect(IP, PORT) # I don't want it to listen to the a specific IP, just any on that port.
```

I am using socket library in python.

Thank you very much,

Comment: What you describe is exactly what servers do. They *listen* on their address and port and will accept connections from *any* IP address. You could do a google search for *python tcp/ip client and server*.

Comment: Thank you, just could not figure out what to search in google. Sorry for my stupidity.

Comment: The *"cannot figure out google search"* thing is not stupidity, just lack of experience.

Answer (score 0):

a server must have an IP, even its 127.0.0.1 which is localhost.
The server is listening  on a Port for a TCP Connection.
If you are not on the same computer, one need to check the IP for the Server.
The Server must be in same subnetwork and the IP/Port must not be blocked by a firewall.
Than the Client can connect via TCP Socket to this IP Address on a specific port.

See: https://realpython.com/python-sockets/

Use the Echo Server and Echo Client

- test it locally first
- after success play with the PORT see it works with changes
- check the IP of the Server PC (with: "ip a" for example)
  and run the Client on a different PC with changeging HOST.